# API Rest with symfony3 : serialization yaml files doesn't work

Tags: json, serialization, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a symfony 3 project with FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle installed with this configs:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    format_listener: false
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: true

jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true

    visitors:
        json:
            options: 0 # json_encode options bitmask

    handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format: "c"
            default_timezone: "UTC"
```

I have an Entity Insertion:

```
{# src/MyBundle/Entity/Insertion.php #}

namespace MyBundle\Entity

class Insertion
{   
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $date;


    // With getter and setter
}
```

I created a config file for serialization

```
{# src/MyBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Insertion.yml #}

MyBundle\Entity\Insertion:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: false
        name:
            expose: true
```

And finally i create the API controller:

```
{# src/MyBundle/Controller/API/InsertionController.php #}

namespace MyBundle\Controller\API;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;

class InsertionController extends FOSRestController 
{
    /**
    * Return all insertions
    *
    * // Some Params
    *
    * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
    * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
    */
    public function getInsertionsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        /** @var InsertionRepository $insertionsRepository */
        $insertionsRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyBundle:Insertion");

        $insertions = $insertionsRepository->findByParameters($paramFetcher);
        $view = $this->view($insertions, 200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

When i call the api I get all insertion's properties exposed (the yaml file doesn't work). The Insertion class also has many related class which not appars in JSON. I tried all configurations but I can't still get serializer yaml file working...

How to solve?